# Java: find JSON object attribute as exact JSON substring (with exact formatting)

Tags: java, json

I need to extract a field from a JSON object as a substring with exactly the same formatting and all whitespaces preserved.

For example when I have this object:

```
{
    "body": 
     {
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Smith"
     },
    "signature": "message_signature"
}
```

I need to extract the field `body` as an exact sub-string.

So the result should look like this:

```
    {
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Smith"
    }
```

I cannot use a standard JSON library such as Jackson, because it parses the JSON into a tree structure and the formatting is lost. I need some library which would be able to return the original sub-string for any given node.

The reason why I need this is to verify the message signature, which takes into account all the whitespaces (it's a 3rd-party API, can't do anything about that).

Comment: https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert if i remember correctly JSONassert can also compare JSON as a String

Comment: *The reason why I need this is to verify the message signature, which takes into account all the whitespaces (it's a 3rd-party API, can't do anything about that).* - This is as it should be, my question is about the `body` field: if you need to preserve formatting, whitespaces etc you shouldn't be parsing it at all. If you need to verify a signature you should have the exact string, not an object in a format which doesn't preserve formatting or key order. Is there any possibility for you to get it as string?

Comment: @BackSlash _Is there any possibility for you to get it as string?_ - That's what I'm asking in this question ;)

Comment: can you use regex and loop through it ? get all between { }

Comment: @AlexSusanu nope because first you have a problem with nested brackets, which can be overcome. But the bigger issue is that you can potentially have brackets inside strings in the JSON body, which would also not work in the regex.

Comment: @Jardo I meant to get it as string from source. I meant you should look for a way to get it returned as a string instead of trying to convert it yourself hoping to preserve everything you had in the source object. Every conversion is potentially losing some important bit and you'll never cover all possible scenarios. Whoever is passing you that object should pass you the body as string so that you can easily read it and verify the signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with Jackson by writing a custom deserializer for your body property. In the deserializer you would then extract the value raw between the starting "{" and ending "}".

See a showcase here (ignoring proper error/edge case handling):

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        var json = """
                    {
                            "body":
                             {
                                "name": "John",
                                "surname": "Smith"
                             },
                            "signature": "message_signature"
                        }
                """;

        var om = new ObjectMapper();

        System.out.println(om.readValue(json, Data.class));
    }

    public static class BodyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

        @Override
        public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

            var startBody = (int) jp.getCurrentLocation().getCharOffset();
            jp.skipChildren();
            var endBody = (int) jp.getCurrentLocation().getCharOffset();

            var rawJson = jp.getCurrentLocation().getSourceRef().toString();

            return rawJson.substring(startBody - 1, endBody);
        }
    }

    public static class Data {

        @JsonProperty("body")
        @JsonDeserialize(using = BodyDeserializer.class)
        public String body;

        @JsonProperty("signature")
        public String signature;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Data [body=" + body + ", signature=" + signature + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thaks!